# How to restore my tabs from onetab chrome extension backup?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

As many on the net I had a problem in my Windows 10 and I had to create a new user. I lost thousands of tabs inside the onetab extension so I tried to copy leveldb from backup to new user folder and restart chrome but still no tabs so this method must be no longer work. Please advise how to restore tabs